# android.support.v7.widget.SearchView setQueryHint?

Tags: java, android

I wanted to add an hint to my `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView` and found [setQueryHint](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html#setQueryHint%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) that refers to `android.widget.SearchView`, how can I set the query hint using `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`?

**Edit:**

To clarify, although `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView` should have `setQueryHint`, it doesn't.

Here are the list of all my dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.15.0'
compile 'com.parse:parsefacebookutils-v4-android:1.10.4@aar'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.1'
compile 'com.parse:parsetwitterutils-android:1.10.5'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding-appcompat-v7:0.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
```

The minSdk is 19 and the targetSdk is 24

Some code snippets:

At the top: `import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;`

And the code:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);

    if (searchItem != null) {
        searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    }
    if (searchView != null) {
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        searchItem.setQueryHint("Query Hint");
    }

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

And `R.menu.menu_search`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="@string/hint_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way, v7 SearchView has that method too.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SearchView.html#setQueryHint(java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: Android studio saying: `Cannot resolve method`, I wouldn't open that question if that was the case, I see the referenced link but it's not working

Comment: Sure, let me add the snippet to my question

Comment: After updating few things the method is there, thanks.

Comment: Good to hear. Sorry I've had no time to look at it more